# How to view cassandra keyspaces in IntelliJ database tool window?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cassandra, intellij-plugin

Is there a way to add a Cassandra DB to IntelliJ so I can run CQL against it and view the keyspaces, etc?

Comment: Isn't Database browsing a paid feature of Intellij? And DataGrip is the official IDE product for that? Even so, it's just a JDBC connection, so include the jar in whatever plugin, and it should work

Comment: @cricket_007 include what driver?

Comment: Any Cassandra JDBC driver. For example https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/download-drivers

Answer (score 0):

It is done in the same way as you do it for connecting to other databases from IntelliJ IDEA, if you have a JDBC driver for Cassandra.

For example, you can use a Cassandra JDBC driver from cdata.com. In the following article, it describes how to use it in IntelliJ IDEA:

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-jdbc-intellij.rst